# Passing checkbox reults

Tags: android

I am very new at this; I am trying to pass the result of checkbox’s to another activity.  I have tried it a few different ways without success and I would be grateful for some direction. Please any help would be great. Thank you

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.appliance);

    final CheckBox chbxshirleys = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxshirleys);
    final CheckBox chbxdianas = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxdianas);
    final CheckBox chbxzoila = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxzoila);
    final CheckBox chbxsheila = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSheila);
    final CheckBox chbxrobert = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxrobert);
    final CheckBox chbxsam = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxsam);
    final CheckBox chbxcamren = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxcamren);
    final CheckBox chbxricks = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxricks);
    final Button vendorbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vendorbutton);

    vendorbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),ApplianceMessage.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("shirleys", null);
            extras.putInt("vendor", 0);
            myIntent.putExtras(extras);

            String vendor ="";
            if (chbxshirleys.isChecked())
            {
                vendor += chbxshirleys.getText();

            }
            if (chbxdianas.isChecked())
            {
                vendor += chbxdianas.getText();
            }
            if (chbxzoila.isChecked())
            {
                vendor += chbxzoila.getText();
            }
            if (chbxsheila.isChecked())
            {
                vendor += chbxsheila.getText();
            }
            if (chbxrobert.isChecked())
            {
                vendor += chbxrobert.getText();
            }
            if (chbxsam.isChecked())
            {
                    vendor += chbxsam.getText();
            }
            if (chbxcamren.isChecked())
            {
                    vendor += chbxcamren.getText();
            }
            if (chbxricks.isChecked())
            {
                vendor += chbxricks.getText();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve ? Get count of checked items or checkbox data or what ?? Question is not clear.

Comment: I am attempting to pass the results (friends names) of the checked boxs to another activity.  In the new activity, I a creating an sms application to send a message to the checked results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

intent.putExtra("String name", chbxshirleys.isChecked());

In Activity get boolean value

Answer (score 0):

First of all please learn more about checkboxes on android from here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html
And for good example you can look that one:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/
And for pass the result other activity use extras for activity.